# Angularjs ui-select tagging not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, tags, ui-select

**THE SITUATION:**

I have an angular app that sends emails. 
There are three fields: Address - Subject - Text. 
The address field is built using angular [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

The email address can be choosen from the list or it may be entered anew. 
The problem is that i am not able to create a new entry.

In the documentation there is written that in order to enter a new value it can be used the attribute [tagging](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select).

But i don't why, is not working with me.

**THE CODE:**

(simple new tag add example)

```
<ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">

    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>

    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
        {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>

</ui-select>
```

```
$scope.availableColors = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Magenta','Maroon','Umbra','Turquoise'];
$scope.multipleDemo = {};
$scope.multipleDemo.colors = ['Blue','Red'];
```

**PLUNKER:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/T55LeKK66Idb3lD8DDPz?p=preview

As you can see is not possible to insert a new value.

**QUESTION:**

How can i properly insert a new value in angular ui-select?

Comment: Hello :) Exactly, i want to be able to create a new colour

Comment: I've deleted my answer and had a look at one of the official examples and it doesn't seem to work. I've added a tagging attribute to the first ui-select and entering text followed by Enter or "," doesn't add the text as a tag. http://plnkr.co/edit/EbeqFz3e7fwShtXlbXeN?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Strange no? It should work as it is explained in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plunkers given use 0.8.2. Tagging works with 0.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by some trick with jQuery—

1. Just add class or id to ui-select tag.
2. Add access by id and class in angular controller like this:

   ```
   <ui-select reset-search-input="true" ng-model="myModel.SerialNumber" theme="bootstrap"
           ng-required="true" name="SerialNumber" class="YourClass" Id="YourId">
       <ui-select-match placeholder=" {{'VehicleMaster.SerialNumber'| translate}}">
           {{$select.selected.SerialNumber}}    
       </ui-select-match>
       <ui-select-choices repeat="item in IMEISerialsDropDown | filter: $select.search">
           <div ng-bind-html="item.SerialNumber"></div>
       </ui-select-choices>
   </ui-select>
   ```

   ```
   $(".YourClass").find("input.ui-select-search").on("focusout", function (val) {
       var variable = $(".YourClass").find("input.ui-select-search").val();
       if (variable .length > 0 && variable .length != null) {
           var variableJson = {
                       SerialNumber: variable ,
                   };
                   $scope.myModel.ModelProperty= variableJson;
       }
   });
   ```